# how to add image and sound in notify icon?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a email moderation application for receiving and sending email. i want to add one more functionality to it that is to notify the user when he received new email. Can I use notify icon for this purpose

if yes then how can i add image and sound in notify icon?

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier if you just rolled your own tiny tool window that pops up when the user receives new e-mail. The reason is this:

Perhaps you can change the NotifyIcon's balloon image on a new mail event. But sound isn't related to the NotifyIcon - you would have to manually play a sound on the event.

So why not just create your own control (or extend NotifyIcon) to popup a custom message? Sort of like those antivirus popups: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKk82.png. They look cooler too.